# Can you combine multiple Google App Engine to work as a single application?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

My web app has multiple App Engines. Each App Engine has its own function. Apps were created with PHP as backend in Google App Engine and uses Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Storage for database and storage respectively.

The following Google App Engines are needed to be combined:

- Client Database App
- Permission Database App
- Transactions Database App
- Fields App
- Reports App
- Performance App
- Data Entry App
- Pattern Matching App

They are all coded in PHP and run in Google App Engine. They use Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Storage for storing data. Can they be binded together to function as one?

Comment: Yes. What difficulty do you see?

Answer (score 2):

An App Engine application is made up of one or more "[services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#versions_and_instances)." Many developers only use the "default" service. You can split your app into multiple services and each service has its own `app.yaml` configuration file and its own settings. In fact, an App Engine app could be comprised of services running in different languages (Python for one, PHP for another), and even both runtime environments (Python on flexible environment, PHP on standard environment).

One of the nice things about this "microservices" approach is that you can deploy or rollback the code for each service independently of each other. You can also share resources across them like Datastore or memcache (Memcache and a few others aren't currently supported in the flexible environment though). You can also pick different instance types or scaling options for different services, which could help you optimize costs or performance.

So yes, this is possible and can be a very good practice for many applications.

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of microservices in the app engine. But I am having different engines for each services. Can I link them to work together? Is there a SOP for it or we have to do it by any custom way we feel like doing?

Comment: In which sense do you need to link them together? And what do you mean by saying that each service has a different engine? As @BrettJ suggested, you can even be using a shared storage option across services, as [isolated services share some resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#service_isolation).